# How do you show JSON array in ionic using *ng-For when the keys are integer strings?

Tags: html, json, angular, ionic4, ngfor

I'm using ionic 4 and I'm trying to get a JSON array using TransportAPI via http.get, however, they use integer strings as the key for the objects I'm trying to get, and then there are multiple arrays for each object, like so:

```
{
    "departures": {
        "25": [
            {
                "mode": "bus",
                "line": "25",
                "departure_time": "12:40"
            },
            {
                "mode": "bus",
                "line": "25",
                "departure_time": "13:00",
            }
        ],
        "50": [
            {
                "mode": "bus",
                "line": "50",
                "departure_time": "12:46",
            },
            {
                "mode": "bus",
                "line": "50",
                "departure_time": null,
            },
            {
                "mode": "bus",
                "line": "50",
                "departure_time": "14:46",
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This JSON array is being stored in "testArray: any;" and there are no problems with actually getting it as I can print it to the console log fine. After hours I only just found out you **have to put number keys into bracket notation** ie. ["25"] to access those, however I'm not sure how to go about this when using *ngFor, or even if you would. This is the rough code I'm trying to output:

```
<div *ngFor="let bus of testArray.departures"> //this is where I'm not too sure

    <ion-item-divider>
        <ion-label> bus line: {{ bus.line }}</ion-label>
    </ion-item-divider>

    <ion-item *ngFor="let time of bus"> //no idea what I'm doing here either
        {{ time.departure_time }}
    </ion-item>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: this is the code I'm using to get the JSON file (missing imports and component etc to save space:

```
export class BusesPage implements OnInit {
  testArray: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  fillTestArray(){
      this.http.get('assets/test.JSON').subscribe(data => {
          this.testArray = data;
          console.log(this.testArray);
      });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.fillTestArray();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is data you wish to iterate through, you need to use the keyvalue pipe as this is an object. The *ngFor without is for iterating through arrays. This will let you iterate through the object.

You can then iterate through the array nested inside the object without the keyvalue pipe. which should show the data you want.

```
<div *ngIf="testArray">  // checks testArray exists
    <div *ngFor="let bus of testArray.departures | keyvalue">
        <div *ngFor="let data of bus.value">
            <ion-item-divider>
                <ion-label> bus line: {{ data.mode }}</ion-label>
                <ion-label> bus line: {{ data.line }}</ion-label>
                <ion-label> bus line: {{ data.departure_time }}</ion-label>
            </ion-item-divider>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[keyvalue pipe docs](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe).

[Angular's displaying data guide](https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data).

Comment: I feel like I'm getting somewhere but I keep getting "Cannot read property 'departures' of undefined", I thought I'd try make it typesafe by adding "testArray?.departures" but that just gave me "Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."

Comment: I have made an edit above, im guessing data comes from api etc, has a small wait when loading so wrap it up in an *ngIf checking the data exists before it trys to draw the *ngFor. If that doesnt help please show how you are getting the data :-)

Comment: I just tried adding the *ngIf but I'm still getting "Cannot read property 'departures' of undefined", I'm no longer calling it from the API directly because I start running out of hits (max 1000 a day on free version which is more than fair) so I copied it into a JSON file, the code I'm using to access it is:
[added as edit above so it can be viewed properly]

Comment: oops, check edit again. Just needs to be testArray I think. Does the console.log show you the correct data ? testArray.departures would error because its trying to access departures on undefined, my bad. Just *ngIf="testArray"

Comment: Damn, yeah the console.log shows everything correctly, I changed "testArray.departures" to "testArray" but still getting "Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."

Comment: Ive stopped being lazy and checked in a stackblitz, last edit try above, needs to be bus.value in the second *ngFor, think thats because of keyvalue pipe :-)

Comment: Oh my god, thank you so much, it's actually working! I've spent about 6 hours on this now, you're a hero <3